# Google Script: returning text from gsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet containing a script. This script creates some text which should be:

- copied to clipboard or
- presented in a web browser (and then I'll copy it to clipboard
  manually) or
- saved to a specific file on hard drive (and then I'll open the file
  and copy the text to clipboard)

My current solution, creating a new gdoc file with the text, (and opening it and copying the text to clipboard each time the script runs) is rather slow and creates plenty of docs which need to be deleted later.

I tried to write `return ContentService.createPlainTextOutput(txt);` in the gsheet script, but this results in error "TypeError: Cannot find function createPlainTextOutput in object ContentService".

Comment: Why not just email it using GmailApp.sendEmail()? Docs here: [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

Comment: This will produce plenty of emails. Well, if there is no easy solution, then I'll stick with creating docs. But the script will be run many many times (esp. during development), so faster method of getting the output is better.

Comment: Is it a lot of text? If not, how about just using Logger.log() to display it? (Logger will truncate text output if it is too long) 
Another option is to write it to a separate sheet in the spreadsheet - I use this for logging errors/scheduled executions for a lot of my apps. Again, if the text is very long or has to be formatted in some specific way, it might not work.

Comment: The logger is quite nice. My text should not be more than 10K characters, so far it is 7.5K and it fits within the logger. I can't find the limit of characters in the docs, but it should be fine. I'd accept this solution as answer.

Comment: Cool. I'll write a proper answer listing possible options, which you can then accept. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Google Apps Script is executed on the server (Google servers), it has no access to your clipboard, or your file system. So those are not the options you are looking for.

Presenting text output in a browser (outputting it to a web page) is possible, provided your script is run as a stand-alone web app, and not attached to a container like a Spreadsheet or Doc. In this case your server-side function should return the text back to the page, which you can then display in a div or another container using javascript.

Other options, including what you are currently doing, are:

- Write the text to a Google Doc or Spreadsheet. An alternative to what
  you are currently doing - creating a Google Doc each time you run
  your script - may be to append the text to the end of the same
  document every time, maybe including a timestamp at the beginning of
  each new addition as well (for easier searching/referencing).
  However, as this document grows in size, this operation may run
  slower and slower. Some sort of rotation of the document may be in
  order in that case. If the amount of text is not too big, appending
  it to a sheet in a designated spreadsheet may be an option, too (with
  a timestamp in the next column for reference). Either way, this will
  let you have a record of all the text output from your script, all in
  one place.
- Send the text as email. Using GmailApp.sendEmail() method is an easy
  way to get your text output. It is very fast if you use an Google
  Apps email account under same domain as your script is running under.
  Set up a filter in Gmail to apply a label to such emails. I do this a
  lot in my apps.
- Use Logger to log the text output. Logger.log() is a quick way to
  display the text output on screen. View the log under menu View->Log.
  Keep in mind that Logger does have a limit on amount of text it can
  display - don't know exactly what the limit is, but I have definitely
  run into truncated output before (though it was A LOT of data I was
  logging). Logs are rotated with every execution of the script, so if
  you need to preserve the output text, you will have to copy/paste it
  from the log to somewhere else.

The best option will depend on the amount of text you need to output, and any special requirements like formatting.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

There is another solution that I (personally) find more easy to use :

create a popup window containing the text that you will be able to copy and paste everywhere.
You can use html formated output or plain text, depending on what you need/prefer.

A simple code from within a spreadsheet would be like this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(400).setHeight(600);
  var html = app.createHTML();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getActiveRange().getValues();
  var string = '<b>Copy and paste the text below<br><br></b>';
  for(var n in data){
    string += data[n].join(' - ')+'<br>';
  }
  html.setHTML(string);
  app.add(html);
  ui.showModelessDialog(app,'toClipboard...');
}
```

Call this from a menu, a button or even adapt it to fit in the sidebar...

[image]

---

### EDIT :

Just saw in comments that your text could be (very) long, I thought it might be advisable to add a scroll panel... code below :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(400).setHeight(600);
  var html = app.createHTML();
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel(html).setPixelSize(400,600);
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getActiveRange().getValues();
  var string = '<b>Copy and paste the text below<br><br></b>';
  for(var n in data){
    string += data[n].join(' - ')+'<br>';
  }
  html.setHTML(string);
  app.add(scroll);
  ui.showModelessDialog(app,'toClipboard...');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I get `UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead.` - posted an adapted version as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I liked [Serge's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26041608/1026) of displaying the string in the spreadsheet's UI, but unfortunately the specific solution was using a deprecated API (`UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead.`). Here's an adapted version I came up with:

```
function myFunction() {
  function displayTextInSidebar(text) {
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b>Copy and paste the text below<br><br></b>" +
                                                  "<pre>").appendUntrusted(text).append("</pre>")
      .setTitle('Output from Apps Script')
      .setWidth(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(htmlOutput);
  }
  //displayTextInSidebar("<b>foobar</b>")
  displayTextInSidebar(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValues().map(function(row) { return row.join(" - "); }).join("\n"))
}
```