# Why APPS SCRIPT function is NOT returning a text or array of text?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The google apps script is here. This function would not return text or string I want. Instead says *Returned number is: abc@cd.com undefined*

I have funciton to check email input from web app and return some sentence such as "your email is abc@abc.com is saved in our record".

```js
function getEmailFromWebAPP(email='abc@cd.com'){

  
  let input = email; //save text.
  var mailformat = /^w+([.-]?w+)*@w+([.-]?w+)*(.w{2,3})+$/;
  //If the parsed number is a number, return calculated number otherwise return error.
  if(input.match(mailformat)){
      return updateText_(input)[0];
  };
  Logger.log(input);
  return `<em style='color:red'> Enter proper email address!`;
};
```

Following function will create a sentence and include the valid email in it. (that part is not included in the code below for, I am still not able to return a text from this function.)

```js
function updateText_(input="abc@cd.com"){
  Logger.log("type:"+typeof input);
  var output = [];
  return output.push(input);
}
```

I also tried with returning *input* directly. But result is same.
Why and how to get test as return value.

Comment: This function always returns 1 because .push() returns the new length of the array according to the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: What _is_ the text or string you want to return? What is this function supposed to do? What is the goal of the array?

Comment: @Ivar This function is being called from another function validating the input variable from html form input element. Once input is validated and then this function is called else alerted.

Comment: @k.b Alright, but _why_ are you calling this function when the input is validated? What is this function supposed to do? You can't expect us to know how to fix something if you don't tell us what it is meant to be doing. That is like asking someone "I want you to make a painting of this person you don't know", without telling them what that person looks like.

Comment: Regarding your edit, your function doesn't seem to have goal. It seems as if you try to add an element to an array and then try to return that array and get the first element again. You end up with the very value you had in the first place. Change `return updateText_(input)[0];` to `return input;` and you'll have the same result.

Comment: @Ivar, actually I just need some extra ornamental things around "input" to complete sentence and then return. For this a separate function is required. I know it is possible to have it just before calling the function, yet my plan is independent function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return `output` after pushing a value into it, you need to modify your code as following:

```js
function runMe(){
    input ="abc@cd.com";
    Logger.log(updateText_(input));
  }
  
  function updateText_(input){
    Logger.log("type:"+typeof input);
    var output = [];
    output.push(input);
    return output;
  }
```

Comment: I got same log message @ziganotschka "Returned number is: abc@cd.com undefined". I just come across this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038370/google-script-returning-text-from-gsheet-script) - as per this returning text from apps script function is not allowed.

Comment: It is hard to see from your code snippet how you call function `updateText-` and to where you return `output` - I updated my code with a sample function calling `updateText-`  correctly with a properly assigned parameter. Also mind that depending on the circumstances you might need to JSON.stringify your object before returning it (e.g. if you are passing it to the client-side of a WebApp).